# iOS firebase auth current user get nil when restart app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase-authentication

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:
```

In my case, When I first time open app and sign in firebase account like above code
then I reopen app

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

user is not nil and then I reopen app get currentUser again  user is nil that mean I did not sign in

I have the other app do like this, but the user always not nil.

I wonder why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically restores the authenticated user when the app restarts. But this requires a call to the servers, which may take some time. If you check `Auth.auth().currentUser` while the check is still in progress, you will get `nil` as the result.

To ensure you get the value once this initial check is done, use an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). From there:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  // ...
}
```

Once this listener fires for the first time:

- either the `user` variable will have a value if the user authentication state could be restored,
- or it is `nil` if the user was not signed in last time the app ran, or the authentication state couldn't be restored (for example, because the account is disabled, or the password was changed).

Comment: Thank u for reply, i add listener the user is nil, is this any other reason that the authentication state couldn't be restored ??

Comment: if you initiate firebase auth, it takes a second to fetch the user. You are dealing with what is known as a race condition. simply waiting for the user to be logged in on app start is all you need - this is typically done with an `onAuthStateChanged` listener

Comment: Can you edit your question to (also) show the code where you use a listener like the one in my answer? If the user is still firing as `nil` in there, it is indeed likely Firebase can't restore the credentials. That is quite uncommon though, and typically the SDK would log why it can't restore the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I think it a big possibility you might be signed in on another device or signed in a different profile and didn't know, you might have some sync problems or security issues that did a safety measurement until you fix the security issue

Comment: Thank u for reply, that seem make sense.